# How to draw rectangle by outside custom button event handler

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw a rectangle by using a Custom Dom Element like

```
<button id="rect">Draw</button>
```

and here is the script which I am using

```
var drawingStyle = {
                    strokeWeight: 0,
                    fillOpacity: 0.45,
                    editable: true,
                    draggable: true,
                   }; 

 google.maps.event.addListener(rect, 'click', function() {
     var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
     drawingControlOptions: {
            drawingModes: [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
        },
        rectangleOptions: drawingStyle,
        map: map
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
  });
```

but clicking on the `#rect` is not causing any event! not even any error on the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#rect` is a DOM object.  To listen for events on it with the Google Maps Javascript API v3 event listeners, use the [addDomListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) method.

```
<button id="rect">Draw</button>

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('rect'), 'click', function() {
    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
           drawingModes: [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
      rectangleOptions: drawingStyle,
       map: map
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
});
```

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 45,
      lng: -85
    },
    zoom: 4
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('rect'), 'click', function() {
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
    // rectangleOptions: drawingStyle,
    map: map
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<button id="rect">Draw</button>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```